# Flutter: How to go Back from WishList Page(index: 1) back button to Home Screen(index:0)

Tags: android, flutter

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MLRD.png)

[WishList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MX7E.png)

I landed on HomeScreen[index : 0] after loginPage but when i go from homePage to WishList Page[index : 1] then i press back button it will not going to back to homePage. why??

Please Give the SolN to my problem

Comment: It would be better to close the AppBar-leadingWidget in the upper left corner of the screen on the pages located on the BottomNavigationBar.
But if you still want to use it, you should access the variable that controls the index of the BottomNavigationBar from the BackButton and change the index from there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define custom logic for your use case.

Naturally what the implied back button does is pops the current route.

Since you need to change page instead of popping route you need to override the default function by passing a custom function to `BackButton`.

An example would be something like :

```
void onPressedBack(){

  //currentIndex is a placeholder var for the attribute or property
  // that has current index information

  if(currentIndex==1){

   //change page to 0 [home] 

   currentIndex=0;

  }

}
```

You can also set automaticallyImpyLeading to false.

also Android has back button (at least older ones) so you need to make sure you handle that as well...

since there’s no code provided, I’m afraid thats all I have to share!

Resources :

[BackButton docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BackButton-class.html) 
[leading AppBar property docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/leading.html)
[WillPopScope widget for system back key gesture docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html)